# Changes to HTML from JavaScript not staying

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

I'm trying to hide a div when a submit is done from a form. The changes happen but when the alert("link") ends, it all goes back to how it was.

#### JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function checarLogin(user, pass){
        var e;
        if (user.value == "a") {
            if (pass.value == "b") {
                alert("Bienvenido.");
                e = document.getElementById('login').style.display='none';
                alert("link");
            } else
            alert("Usuario o clave incorrectos.");
        } else
            alert("Usuario o clave incorrectos.");

    }
</script>
```

#### HTML:

```
<div id="login">
    <form onsubmit="checarLogin(user, pass)">
    Ingrese usuario y clave para ver los documentos.
    <div id="inlogin" display="none">
        <br><br>
        Usuario <input name="user" type="text"><br><br>
        Clave <input name="pass" id="clave" type="password"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="descargas">
    Descargables.
    <div id="indescargas">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide the login DIV.

Comment: Is this submitting back to the same page? If so the page will be refreshed from the server _after_ your JS runs, so... (You could hide the div with some server-side code, or set and check a cookie value, or...)

Comment: Can you use JQuery? It makes things like this much easier. I can explain if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit a form it does a round trip to the server. Most likely the page is refreshing and this causes the content to go back to the way it was. You could test this by making your page tall, scroll down and submit. If you bounce back to the top then the page has refreshed.

To work around this you would want to submit the form data using an ajax request instead.

Comment: Ok, I understand... I don't know how to use ajax, so:
how can i make it instead of hiding going to a new link??

Comment: @chamini2 - you don't have much choice other than AJAX. You need to send the login information to the server so that it can be validated. Ajax accomplishes this without refreshing the page. If you use a library like jQuery this becomes very easy to do. You can ask a new question if necessary. The other option is to handle this server side. When a user is authenticated you hand back a different page that doesn't include the login area.

Answer (score 0):

The page is submitting to itself, adding return false should do it. http://jsfiddle.net/Y6x5N/

```
<form onsubmit=" return checarLogin(user, pass);">
```

and

```
function checarLogin(user, pass){
    var e;
    if (user.value == "a") {
        if (pass.value == "b") {
            alert("Bienvenido.");
            e = document.getElementById('login').style.display='none';
            alert("link");
        } else {
        alert("Usuario o clave incorrectos.");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Usuario o clave incorrectos.");
    }
return false;

}​
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the form is being submitted to the server. I assume that what you are trying to accomplish is an authentication feature? And once the user has been authenticated, the **login** `div` will be removed?

I suggest that you do the authentication in your site within the server side. If you plan to continue with this, the password will be printed out in your `javascript` block and will become easily readable by users. Once the user has been successfully authenticated, the server can easily give back another page without the **login** `div`. Easier and more secure.

Comment: just like in his example, `if (pass.value == "b") {` his password is `b`